# Crystal Disk Info shows caution, reallocate sector count, do I need to worry?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I recently got to know about a tool named crystal disk info, I installed it on my laptop and ran it and everything was good and the health status it showed was `good`. Until yesterday also it was in `good` status. Suddenly today when I ran the tool it's showing `caution`. Reallocated Sector Count is 1.
I have attached a screenshot below of the same.

I wanted to know the reason behind this sudden fault. Is running is application regularly safe? I ran this application along with with other applications already running like chrome, did that create some problem? Also, I am skeptical that this problem is originated because of crystal disk info only because everything was fine till then. Do I need to worry? Is there some other way I can verify this?

**UPDATE**

1. I also ran the wmic command and it says the status is ok.
2. I also went into C: drive properties and under tools ran a check and it also
   turned out to be okay.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Disk Info has a solid reputation, so its a good tool to use. All it is doing is reporting on what the disk thinks of itself. (There are plenty of other tools that do the same thing).  The change in HDD status is most likely coincidental, and you will not likely be able to pinpoint any particular piece of software that triggered it (and it would not be the fault of that software anyway - these problems exist below the level that most software works at)

HDD's are a bit tricky and SMART (the info on the drive that is being read) is difficult to interpret and not overly reliable - but it is an indicator your HDD is not doing great. FWIF, HDDs are the most likely component to fail in a computer, and are the most important.

At minimum you should be ensuring you have a very good backup regimin and check your backups are usable -and it can't hurt to look towards replacing your disk (with an SSD?)

Comment: I was thinking of adding an additional 500Gb nvme ssd, but now there's an error on this one only. So, I am confused what to do now, I don't want to expend enough on this laptop. Should I add that extra ssd, I was planning to clone my OS into that. What would you suggest?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying above. Also, how full is your current disk and how old is your computer?

Comment: It's just an year old, it's only 20% full. I was saying that to enhance the performance of my machine I was thinking of adding an additional 500gb of ssd (there's a M.2 slot provided for the same) along with the current harddisk (this ways my system would have had a total of 1.5 TB storage), but now since this has become faulty I will have to replace this harddisk with a 1TB harddisk (I need 1TB storage) which will be costlier. Also, please read my updated question. I ran other tests which went fine.

Comment: If its only 20% full after 1 year, why do you need 1tb storage? Your disk could very well be OK and might still have a long life,  but you should keep an eye on it and if the reallocated sector count starts going up significantly  you should replace it. Adding an SSD and keeping key docs on it is not a bad idea either.

Comment: Yaa I am also thinking that only, btw can you suggest some other tools that I can use to test reallocated sectors, because the windows wmic command currently says okay. Can I use wmic command to monitor my harddisk's health in future or I will have to use third party tools only?

Comment: I don't use Windows so can't advise well on Windows tools. https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download is well reputed. Note you are not testing reallocated sectors, you are only viewing what the HDD says.

Answer (score 0):

Som,

you should have shown the rest of the diagnosis. That's why I prefer the log file of smartmontools even if it's less comfortable to use.

Check your "pending sectors" count.

Don not rely on one-dimensional simplifications like "good" or "caution" by Crystal Disk Info.

Instead compare the results with other drives you have.
That gives you an idea about what seems to be normal.

One broken sector does not necessarily mean that the life of your drive is over.

Monitor the parameters daily and increase the control intervals if the pending sector count and the reallocating sector count does not increase.

Do look at the other parameters as well.